# How To Update Form Value Of Task in WSO2BPS

Tags: wso2, workflow, activiti, wso2-business-process

I am using wso2bps-3.6.0 and created a workflow for task approval. In this workflow, I have created multiple tasks and each task have their own form. I am able to insert and retrieve value from form but i am not able to update this form value.

Please let me know, which wso2bps rest api should i call to update form value.

Answer (score 0):

You can update form values by updating variables related to form entries. Please refer [15.7.10. Create (or update) variables on a task](https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#_create_or_update_variables_on_a_task) in Activiti User Guide for detailed information.

Note: Since WSO2 BPS uses Activiti BPMN engine, almost all functionalities provided in it are available and similar in WSO2 BPS BPMN Rest API.

~Mili~